# How do I resolve this desync issue?

Tags: diablo-iii

Ever since 1.04 came out, I've managed to desync the game twice.  I'm not 100% sure what I did to cause it in the first place, but when it happens, it looks like this:

[image: Cropped screenshot of game while experiencing the problem]

Symptoms include:

- Unable to die.  The damage I take is fairly significant, but my life never hits 0.  I don't die.
- Unable to move.  This is like the previous de-sync issue, where you'd rubberband once you got a certain distance away from the de-sync point, and then you'd be fine.  But now, the distance is point blank, and moving away doesn't resolve the issue.  So it looks like massive stutter when I move.
- Can't be seen.  I'm entirely invisible.  Anything that affects me shows the various effects where I'm supposed to be, but I can't see myself at all.  I still take damage normally, though.
- Can't attack.  Shift-clicking does nothing, attacking anything that's close enough to hit does no damage.
- Can't use special abilities.  It's like it doesn't register that I'm using special abilities.
- Can't use Town Portal.  Same as special abilities; it's like it doesn't register at all.
- Buffs continue to countdown.  I can't refresh them (see special abilities above), but they continue to count down as usual.

My usual fix for desyncing is to move far enough away from the point to allow the server to resync me.  But, I can't move at all; the rubberbanding just dumps me right back, without resyncing properly.  In those cases, I use Dashing Strike to fix the issue.  But special abilities are out entirely, too.

The only way I know of to fix this is to leave my game.  This is not really fun, as I'll lose my valor stacks when I do so.

If anyone has a technique or way to resolve this that doesn't involve leaving the game, please let me know.

Comment: I honestly don't think there is a solution to this beyond "relog" - obviously with the nature of the way things work in Diablo 3 re-logging every time a problem like this crops up is definitely counter productive to actually playing the game...

Comment: Are you sure it's a simple de-sync and not a more serious problem like a persistent network connection problem?  Your symptoms sound more like a dropped connection than just a de-sync.

Comment: @MBraedley Positive.  I regularly browse internet without issue while I'm gaming.  I also managed to get a friend to join the game, and I could see him running around me without a problem.

Comment: i'd recommend keeping a cmd window open in the background with ping -n 10000000 www.google.com to see if your ping times spike up

Comment: You can also use ping www.google.com /t as well. The /t trigger makes the ping run "forever", until you stop it by hitting CTRL+C or closing the CMD window.

If you want, you can do: ping -n 500 www.google.com >> c:\pingtest.txt. This will ping google 500 times, and save the data as a file named pingtest.txt on your C drive. Replace C with another drive letter if required. This lets you run the ping test without having to actually pay attention to it, and you can search the txt document for mentions of package-loss as well. In other words, it makes it more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Desyncing issues have been (at least mostly) addressed in recent patches, as well as the removal of Valor stacks, making disconnecting less of a bad thing.